# What is it called when an animal only has one type/variation of dentition?

Tags: terminology, teeth

An example would be alligators that only have one type/shape of tooth. Not the variation in function and shape like seen in humans, which have canines, molars, incisors, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Homodont**

You can find the term "homodont" used in [Lambert et al. (2014)](http://www.bioone.org/doi/abs/10.5252/g2015n1a4) or on [wikipedia > dentition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dentition) for examples. The opposite of homodont is heterodont [(wikipedia > heterodont)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterodont). In mammals, a classical example of homodonts is the dolphin.

Comment: to reinforce heterodont dentition is fairly rare, only mammals with their limited number of teeth have it constantly across a large clade.